# Is it possible to do a sandwich attack on the Solana network?

Tags: solana-program

I recently noticed this wallet below, carrying out a series of transactions that look like a sandwich attack (but I'm not sure if it is).. Does anyone know what this person is doing?

Wallet: `https://solscan.io/account/DCAKxnquJnRYHDqp3qzyBS4qztddcbEQsGv68z6boUwr#splTransfers`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sandwich attacks on Solana. Is this a problem?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8821/sandwich-attacks-on-solana-is-this-a-problem)